# Is there something like Perl's Win32::FileNotify for Linux or OS X?

Tags: perl, file, cross-platform, cpan, last-modified

I've been using [Win32::FileNotify](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-FileNotify) on Windows, and I was curious to know if there were something similar for Linux and OS X. I haven't been able to find such a module using Google. Does anyone here know of such a thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[File::ChangeNotify](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-ChangeNotify/) sounds like a cross-platform way to do this.

Comment: This! File::ChangeNotify is what Catalyst's development server uses to initiate a restart when a file changes. It's got nice, fast file watcher classes for Linux, BSD and Win32 (I recently contributed the KQueue watcher for *BSD :)), and a fallback that polls files for changes. It's pretty heavily used by people working with Catalyst, so I imagine it's pretty stable.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know of a specific cross platform solution there is inotify on linux (well on modern kernels from 2.6.13) and from the [Inotify](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Linux-Inotify) module from CPAN. As for OS X, there is apparently the `kqueue` syscall but I have no experience of using it.

Answer (score 1):

For systems where [famd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_alteration_monitor) can run (Irix, Linux, BSDs, most Unices) there is [SGI::FAM](http://search.cpan.org/~jglick/SGI-FAM-1.002/lib/SGI/FAM.pm) and [Sys::Gamin](http://search.cpan.org/~garnacho/Sys-Gamin-0.1/lib/Sys/Gamin.pm), both of which do not build straight out of CPAN or tarball, but do work well once you get them working.